# Гироскоп акселерометр android

Tags: java, android

У меня есть webview,который открывает сайт с WebGl или CCS3D. На данном сайте есть кнопка,которая включает гироскоп.

Если зайти на этот сайт через chrome и нажать на эту кнопку,гироскоп включается.
Если запустить сайт через webview в android app, то при нажатии на кнопку 
гироскопа,сайт не крутиться,как это происходит в chrome.

Вопрос: как включить гироскоп на android,чтобы при нажатии на кнопку гироскопа сайт так же крутился как и в chrome?

Подключены следующие разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true" />
```

Код:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    WebView webView;
    final String ulr="http://sfer***.com/hodite/";
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor sensor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        //webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl(ulr);

        /*sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);*/


    }
```

Comment: а использование акселирации прописано в манифесте? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787269/uses-feature-accelerometer-in-the-manifest

Comment: @pavel нет,не прописано.Сейчас прописал 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
но ничего не изменилось